# creating stored procedure - syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I keep getting a syntax error, I've look at countless examples I'm not sure what the problem is...

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
  SELECT *  FROM user;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

SCREENSHOT:
[image]

Comment: There are 6 lines in your SQL code, what do you have on line 7?

Comment: @mitkosoft I have nothing underneath that no whitespace or anything...

Comment: The code works as a charm in my Navicat.

Comment: This code is working fine in mysql work bench.

Comment: wth that so weird...

Comment: wow so apparently if I remove the `CREATE PROCEDURE test()` and just use the `BEGIN` through `END` it gets created fine... I think new update in NaviCat (11.2.11 Enterprise)

Comment: I guess they make you write the parameters here --- http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/How_can_I_create_function_or_procedure_/_input_values_with_more_than_one_input_parameter%3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter procedure and remove delimiter....like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
  SELECT *  FROM user;
END
```

Comment: I get a different error now -  "Can't create a PROCEDURE from within another stored routine"

Answer (score 0):

Modify the user to [user] as user is reserved keyword

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
SELECT *  FROM [user];
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced multiple problems when wanting to create a stored procedure in Navicat.

Finally I wrote the CREATE PROCEDURE-statement in the normal query window instead of inside the window to design a function/procedure, and then it worked.